# Multiple select queries with multiple where statements

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have this query:

```
SELECT s.firstName, s.lastName, sum(correct) AS score 
FROM student s 
JOIN test t ON s.id = t.studentid 
WHERE t.testType = 1 GROUP BY lastName, firstName
```

But I also want it to show

```
WHERE t.testType = 2
```

and testType 3 and 4 also.

I want to have it all in the same row. Is this possible?

Comment: agreed to @Tiny , @Kewin try using `between` clause

Comment: I figured it out. Just used a bunch of JOIN statements.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `in` style to select from a multiple of different values

```
SELECT s.firstName, s.lastName, sum(correct) AS score 
FROM student s 
JOIN test t ON s.id = t.studentid 
WHERE t.testType in ( 1,2,3,4 ) 
GROUP BY lastName, firstName
```

Comment: that will not show it in the same row though ( which I noticed afterwards )

Comment: Yeah and I would like for it to also have individual columns for each score for each testType

Answer (score 0):

I think between clause can answer your question - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm

```
where t.testType between 1 and 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.firstName, s.lastName, b.score, c.score2
FROM student s 
JOIN (
    SELECT s.id,s.firstName, s.lastName, sum(correct) AS score FROM student s JOIN test t ON s.id = t.studentid WHERE t.testType = 1 GROUP BY lastName, firstName
) b ON (s.id = b.id)
JOIN (
    SELECT s.id,s.firstName, s.lastName, sum(correct) AS score2 FROM student s JOIN test t ON s.id = t.studentid WHERE t.testType = 2 GROUP BY lastName, firstName
) c ON (s.id = c.id)
GROUP BY lastName, firstName
```

I just used a bunch of JOIN statements. It works. Just doesn't show anything if either value is 0.

Comment: You can put instead of  "sum(correct)" , "ifnull(sum(correct),'No scores')"

Comment: That's awesome. I was actually thinking to myself that I would have a problem if it's NULL and I was thinking if/else statements. This is way better though, thanks a lot.

Comment: For some weird reason it doesn't make a difference. Nothing gets outputed if it's false. (Also I'm using 0 instead of No score since the field is an INT)